# How do I determine which paths Laravel 7.x is expecting to find my view file in?

Tags: php, laravel

My code's rather simple:

```
return response()->view("OneTimeLink", [ 'data' => $data ]);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: View [OneTimeLink] not found. in file /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php on line 137
```

In debugging this, I've since learned that it should have a .blade.php extension. I renamed the file, rebuilt the docker image, I get the same error.

I've tried using relative and absolute paths, with proper (and Windows') slashes. Always the same error (though, it will modify the error message to show that it's observing the path I've specified).

If I just output a json'ed getcwd() it shows me that it's working from the /app/public directory (I've no idea if that is normal). So I've also tried using a "../Http/Resources/Views/OneTimeLink" path, with the same results. No doubt I've messed up just where to place the views, and it is a path that Laravel won't actually bother to check, but I'm having trouble determining just where it is wanting to find these.

Is there a debugging technique that will reveal where it is looking, or documentation that specifies where that should be located? Inside the docker container, artisan is claiming Laravel 7.30.4.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views - `Views are stored in the resources/views directory.`

Comment: @aynber The Resources directory was already present in the repo, I manually created a Views directory. Is the uppercasing a problem? Artisan 7.x doesn't have a make:view command, had to do the dirty work myself.

Comment: It should be lowercase. Interesting that it wasn't created automatically, you should have at least the default welcome.blade.php if it hasn't already been overwritten.

Comment: @aynber The people who wrote the app are long gone, I have a github repo and a Dockerfile that took me a week to figure out how to successfully run locally. I've made some changes that tested well, but this is the first where I want non-json output and it's making me want to pull my hair out.

Comment: If you want to return view (non-json output) use `return view("oneTimeLink", compact( 'data'));` instead of `return response()->view("OneTimeLink", [ 'data' => $data ]);` considering the `oneTimeLink.blade.php` ->is already in path: `resources/views/oneTimeLink.blade.php`

Comment: In case if you want to see default laravel's project, you can see [github repo of laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel), by default, the `resources` folder is in same folder as app, public, config, etc..

Comment: @tokkerbaz there's no functional difference between `return view()` and `return response()->view()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `app/config` directory, there should be a "view.php" file. This includes a 'paths' array that probably only includes one entry:

```
resource_path('views'),
```

The standard location is included by default according to a comment, and does not need to be added.

The resource_path() function is also a decent way to try to figure out just where it might be looking for these. I included a debug statement with what it returns, and got the following value:

```
/app/resources/temp
```

This path looked a little weird because I was expecting everything important to be in a path something like /app/Http/resources ... I'd screwed up my Dockerfile and was copying it into /app. So everything needed a /app/app prefix essentially, throwing off the Views and lord knows what else.

Comment: The comment "the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you" means they've added it to the config file, not that it's included by default. The second half of your answer doesn't seem terribly useful to other users.

Comment: @miken32 The downvote didn't seem terribly useful to me either, but it's there. I provided a method of debugging, which is what I asked in the question. Whatever.